# Undertow: Static root-content outside of WAR-file (wildfly)

Tags: jboss, webserver, wildfly, application-server, undertow

I have the following problem, which makes me going nuts:

I want to configure my Undertow-Subsystem of my Wildfly 10.0.0 Final app-server, so it can handle static content on root (/) while a WAR-file is deployed.

When no WAR is deployed, it shows the welcome-content, as configured in the `standalone.xml`:

```
<location name="/" handler="welcome-content"/>
```

and

```
<file name="welcome-content" path="${jboss.home.dir}/welcome-content"/>
```

As soon as my WAR is deployed, no more welcome-content is shown. Until now, exactly, what i wanted. Now i want to extract our angular-client to a seperate directory, lets say `/home/user/awesomeClientDir`.

I tried adding a new `location` and `file`-handler, which works nicely in a subpath like `www.website.com/subpath/index.html`

As soon as i configure the path to `/`, no matter if my welcome-content is still in my `standalone.xml` or not, the WAR-file removes the ability to access my static content.

I have absolutely no idea, how i can achieve this... The `web.xml` in my WAR hooks my API into the `/rest` subpath, wich works great in any case, but my static content just won't be available at `/` (403 / 404 depending on constellation)

Any help or hint will be appreciated, the struggle is real with this one!

Comment: Is your war deployed to / context?

Comment: Yes, it is. I configured resteasy to serve at the /rest subpath, but the war itself is deployed in the root context. Should i change it to /rest and let resteasy serve on root?

Comment: yes you should change context of the app to /rest and have resteasy on root. that will fix your problems.

Comment: I will try this asap, thank you very much so far!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should bind deploy your application (war) to /rest and have the resteasy application listen to root of that application.

This way undertow subsystem can still handle / resource and all others (but /rest) with static content handler (or any other if you want)

Comment: Great, this did the trick. I had a hard time deploying my war at /rest context, the jboss-web.xml didn't work. I just had to rename the WAR from ROOT.war to rest.war, now it works just fine! Thank you so much!